# translate pipe according to URL language Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

I have a translate pipe in Angular2 application. 
I have a component called: LanguageComponent which is the parent for all others.

```
{ path: ':lang', component: LanguageComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent },   
    ]}
```

The language component read the URL and add it to the translate service and the pipe read from this service:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
   this.translate.setCurrentLanguage(params['lang'].toLowerCase());
});
```

everything works correctly and the values in the translate and the params are right. 
but the problem is in the GUI:

```
{{ 'label' | translate }}
```

the pipe is being compiled before the language component. so the value of the 'label' come always as default: 'en-us'

The translate service:

```
public defaultLanguage = 'en-us';
getCurrentLanguage(): any {
   if (this.locale == null) {
     this.locale = window.navigator.language == null ? this.defaultLanguage : window.navigator.language;
   }
   return this.locale;
}
```

the route returns the correct value. but if I set a debugger onInit in the language component and another one inside the language service. the debugger inside the service will be fired up before the other and will read the default value, no matter what value is in the URL.

anybody knows how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build something similar to Angular's [async pipe](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts).

Your pipe's constructor should inject `private _ref: ChangeDetectorRef`.

The `transform` method should store the transformed value in an instance variable and return a `WrappedValue` referencing the instance variable.

It should also subscribe to the current language from the language service.  When the current language changes, it should update the instance variable and then it should call `this._ref.markForCheck()` which will cause the wrapped value to be re-evaluated.

Comment: I did not quite understand. I added the ChangeDetectorRef. but nothing changed. what do you mean with WrappedValue. can you provide me please with code solution? thank you!

Comment: No, I cannot provide a code solution.  I don't currently have the time.  The async pipe implementation I linked above should be a good template to work from.

Comment: okay no Problem thank you anyway for the idea. But I don't have a subscription in my pipe. so where should I use this._ref.markForCheck() ?

Comment: You should change your language service so that the current language is something you can subscribe to.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I did the _ref.markForCheck() after I call the routing and it works.